# How to increase physical memory on an EC2 r3.large instance

Tags: memory, amazon-ec2, jvm, solrcloud

I'm running SolrCloud on six EC2 r3.large instances.  I'm seeing a lot of OOMs,  the cloud console is showing 98% physical memory usage, swap space NaN which I assume means none. It shows JVM usage at about 66%.

Can I upgrade my r3.large's to r3.xlarge's somehow?  I thought this type of upgrade was one of the features of the r3 types.

If not that, any advice on lowering physical mem usage until I can rebuild please.

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question on http://serverfault.com?  This isn't really programming-related.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize an Amazon EC2 instance:

- **Stop** the instance (Right-click, Instance State, Stop)
- Change the **Instance Type** (Right-click, Instance Settings, Change Instance Type)
- **Start** the instance again